# Нужно разбить по понятиям: TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCat);

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.

Помогите, я новичок в Java :)

Нужно разбить по понятиям: `TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCat)`;

`TextView` —
`myTextView` —
`(TextView)` —
`R.id.tvCat` —

В основном понятно, но путаюсь, т.к. есть одинаковые значения.

Comment: Стоит мануалы почитать, прежде чем пытаться прогу запилить на андроид, это элементарщина. Хотя бы пару лекций прочитайте :)

Comment: @jessez ну вот читаю, но там на этом методе не зацикливались)

Comment: Стоит сначала просто азы Java подучить, чтобы понимать, что такое класс, что такое экземпляр класса, что такое приведение типов и т.п. А потом уже за Андроид браться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так будет понятней, не знаю, `TextView myTextView` это Вы создали ссылку, потом через знак равно Вы задаете ссылке объект, на который она будет ссылаться. На простом примере можно показать так 
`String string = new String();` Теперь Вы можете обращаться к раннее созданному объекту `new String()` через ссылку string. Т.е. вызывая методы обращаясь к ссылке `string.replace()` и т.п.

В Вашей ситуации, Вы не создаете новый объект, а так сказать, запрашиваете его, вызывая метод, который возвращает (return) объект типа View, Вы передаете в аргументе метода `findViewById(ТУТ)` айдишник запрашиваемого элемента `findViewById(R.id.tvCat)`. Но так как Вам нужен объект типа TextView, Вы кастите ([статья: приведение типов](http://sernam.ru/book_java.php?id=7)) объект View в TextView, если так можно сделать, иначе будет ошибка.

p.s. я сам новичек, за неточности прошу не пинать))

Comment: ничего страшного, спасибо большое))

Comment: @ikerya не забудьте отметить ответ как правильный, который вам подошел

Comment: оба ответа хороши, даже не знаю :(

Comment: @ikerya выбирайте любой, это не очень существенно, если вопрос исчерпан, то лучше выбрать ответ, что бы вопрос не висел в неотвеченных вопросах

Answer (score 7):

- TextView - класс
- myTextView - переменная типа TextView
- (TextView) - приведение объекта к типу-наследнику (сработает только если findViewById() действительно вернет экземпляр класса TexView, записаны в переменную типа View)
- R.id.tvCat - уникальный идентификатор View-объекта в отдельной XML-разметке

Comment: спасибо, очень благодарен) а на примере какого-то элемента можете показать? там объявление переменной `myTextView ` и т.д.? и что за класс TextView? что он выполняет?

Comment: Вот пример кода, создающего текстовое поле с красным цветом текста. Поле занимает весь экран.
public static TextView createTextViewWith(final Context ctx, final String text) {
    final TextView tw = new TextView(ctx);
    tw.setText(text);
    tw.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    tw.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    return tw;
  }

Comment: буду разбираться, спасибо)

Comment: @ikerya класс `TextView` [относится к группе виджетов](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) системы Android, то есть классов, которые выводят информацию на экран устройства - все, что вы видите на экране реализован с их помощью - кнопки, переключатели, картинки, текст, ползунки и все прочее. Именно класс `TextView` отвечает за вывод текста на экран.

Comment: понял, спасибо. а вот ещё не понятно по поводу этого же класса виджетов обёрнутого в скобки -- (TextView)